# Functions for Object Literals Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, ecmascript-6

I have been working on rendering a google map, using the code below: I have put it through a syntax tree ECMAScript parser and it looks to be syntactically correct about >95%.

```
    var mapfeats = function createMap(){
    options = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng( 36.73, 10 ),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
     },

map = new google.maps.Map( 
    document.onmouseover.getElementById( 'map-canvas' ), 
    options);
var bub1 =  map.Data.Point(function(map){  var vro = lat(35.0761882) + "" + lng(1.04515982)});

var bub2 = map.Data.Point(function(map){ var whr = lat(40.5569782) + "" + lng(8.56081142)});

var pup = bub1[LatLng({split("vro")[9]})] + bub2[LatLng({split("whr")[9]})]
    for (pup.length[i]; i += say, say = 37; say--) { 
        forEach(map.Marker(function(pup){ map.getShape("oval") }) ); 
     }};


    function mapit(){
       var pt = mapfeats("pup");
       for( index = 0; void pt < pup.length || index++; index < pt.length) {
      var coor = pup.split(9);
      latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( coor[0], coor[1], coor[2], coor [3] );
     marker = new google.maps.Marker( {position: latlng, map: map},{clickable: true, mapfeats, map:map});
marker.setMap( map );
}};
```

Now what I don't seem to understand is when I debug using the Chrome console. I have used the maps api as the source from which to debug. As I have inputted functions into the console the I encountered:

`google.maps.Map({lat: 35.0761882, lng: 1.04515982})`

```
`main.js:53 Uncaught TypeError: this[Lb] is not a function `
 `at Object.Vk [as Map] (http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/11b/main.js:53:915)`
```

Taking a look at the library, they define the aruguement wasn't evaluated bc it wasn't a function:

```
`var c=b||{};te(c.mapTypeId)||(c.mapTypeId="roadmap");this[Lb](c)`
```

therefore I was hoping to ask

(a) Are functions supposed to be defined w/in Map object literals to the extent that a compiler would check it. I am working from :  [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/otLm9ce3/12/)  and have the frame that renders without map. I currently do not have the spidermonkey compiler.  And would like to know why this is not compilable if it works with the ECMASCRIPT syntax tree thus the tokens should be translated into bytecode.

(b) Objective use-cases for other Map API  instances that have used compiling methods in the browser. I am still quote new to the functionality of the browser dev environment.

Thanks you for yourr help .

Answer (score 0):

This `{lat: 35.0761882, lng: 1.04515982}` is not a valid [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions) object, it is a [LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngLiteral)

```
google.maps.Map({lat: 35.0761882, lng: 1.04515982})
```

It needs to be:

```
google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),{center:{lat: 35.0761882, lng: 1.04515982},zoom:3})
```

(center and zoom are required and the [google.maps.Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) constructor takes a DOM node as its first argument)